# How can I find tests that haven't been added to a particular test suite?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit4

How can I find tests that have not been added to a test suite?

If I run the test suite I get say 1000 tests but if I run a file search for "@Test" I get 1020 results. How can I go and add the missing ones without having to go through every search result and comparing to the tests that ran to see which ones are missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use Eclipse itself to create a test suite. From the context menu of the project, select 'New -> Other' and select JUnit test suite. It will list out all the test classes in the project. By default, it creates a AllTests.java source file.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with multiple packages?

Comment: Just checked. It goes by source folder and a package. You can't select multiple packages, but you should be able to merge them together once the AllTests.java is created for each package.

Comment: Your packages should be in a hierarchy. right? Just select one of the top level packages.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to do `com.*` packages